# System of nonlinear equations

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I wanted to solve a system of four nonlinear equations, which each equates to 0, and unknowns are: h, C, M0, V0. I tried the code below but strangely enough when I get the results the first equation isn't equal to zero.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

p= 90
b = 45/2
d = 20
c = 500 
E = 205000
I = b*d**3/12
k = b*c
L = (4*E*I/k)**(1/4) 
fy = 355 
W = b*d**2/4

def equations1(everything):
    h,C,V0,M0 = everything
    return ((np.sqrt(2*M0*b*p+V0**2)+V0)/(p*b)-L-h,
            (4*(M0*h+(1/2)*V0*h**2-(1/6)*p*b*h**3+C))/(L**4*b*c),
            -(3*L**2*b*h**2*p+b*h**4*p-6*L**2*W*fy-12*L*W*fy*h+6*W*fy*h**2+12*C*h)/(6*(L**2+h**2))-M0,
            (3*L**2*b*h*p+2*b*h**3*p-6*L*W*fy+6*W*fy*h+6*C)/(3*(L**2+h**2))-V0)
h,C,V0,M0 =  fsolve(equations1, (153,0,800000,-0.1E6))
print('h = {} mm, C = {}, V0 = {} kN, M0 = {} kNm'.format(h, C, V0*1E-3,M0*1E-6))
```

Now when you take the first equation you expect it to be zero:

```
(np.sqrt(2*M0*b*p+V0**2)+V0)/(p*b)-L-h = 0
```

But it's actually:

```
(np.sqrt(2*M0*b*p+V0**2)+V0)/(p*b)-L-h = -24.75
```

Do you know why this isn't closer to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get this warning when I run your code:

```
[...]/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:175: RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
  improvement from the last ten iterations.
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
```

The warning tells you that something did not work.  Unfortunately, there is nothing in the return value to indicate the problem, so if you don't notice the warning, you won't know that there is a problem.

That's why it is generally a good idea to use `fsolve` with the parameter `full_output=True`.  With this parameter set to True, four objects are returned: `x` (the estimated solution), `infodict` (a dictionary containing details of the solution process), `ier` (an integer code; 1 indicates success), and `mesg` (a string containing a convergence message).

In your case,

```
In [37]: x, info, ier, mesg = fsolve(equations1, (153, 0, 800000, -0.1E6), full_output=True)

In [38]: ier
Out[38]: 5

In [39]: mesg
Out[39]: 'The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the \n  improvement from the last ten iterations.'
```

`ier` is not 1, which tells you that the solver did not converge to a solution.

---

Alternatively, you can use the function `root` instead of `fsolve`.  Its return value is always an object with several attributes, including the boolean `success` that indicates success or failure.

```
In [84]: result = root(equations1, (153, 0, 800000, -0.1E6))

In [85]: result.success
Out[85]: False
```

(If `success` was True, you could then use the solution stored in `result.x`.)